# custom hook not firing on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I've created a custom hook to fetch data and am trying to implement it, but to no avail.

This is my custom hook:

```
import { useReducer } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const dataFetchReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_INIT":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        isError: false,
      };
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    case "FETCH_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: true,
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

const useApi = (method) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, {
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false,
    data: null,
  });

  axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://code-portfolio-f44c5.firebaseio.com";

  const fetchData = async (url, data) => {
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_INIT" });

    try {
      const result = await axios[method](url, JSON.parse(data));

      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", payload: result.data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_FAILURE" });
    }
  };

  return [state, fetchData];
};

export default useApi;
```

and this is the modal where I want it to be fired onClick:

```js
const [{ data, isLoading, isError }, doFetch] = useApi("post");

function createSnippet(e) {
  doFetch(`/snippets/${framework}.json`, {
    description: description,
    category: category,
    title: title,
    snippet: snippet,
  });
  e.preventDefault();
}

return (
  <Modal
    isOpen={modalIsOpen}
    shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}
    onRequestClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
    style={modalStyles}
    onAfterClose={resetStateVariables}
  >
    <ModalContainer>
      <HeaderContainer>
        <Header>Add a snippet</Header>
      </HeaderContainer>
      <BodyContainer>
        <Form>
          <InputContainer>
            <LabelledSelect
              label="Select framework"
              options={frameworkOptions}
              onChange={(e) => setFramework(e.target.value)}
              value={framework}
            />
          </InputContainer>
          <InputContainer>
            <LabelledSelect
              label="Select category"
              options={categoryOptions}
              onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}
              value={category}
            />
          </InputContainer>
          <InputContainer>
            <LabelledTextInput
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
              label="Title"
              placeholder="What's the title of this snippet?"
            />
          </InputContainer>
          <InputContainer>
            <LabelledTextarea
              label="Describe your snippet"
              value={description}
              onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="What does your snippet do?"
            />
          </InputContainer>
          <InputContainer>
            <AceEditor
              mode="javascript"
              theme="twilight"
              onChange={setSnippet}
              editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
              setOptions={{
                enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
                enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
                enableSnippets: true,
              }}
              width="100%"
              height="200px"
              value={snippet}
            />
          </InputContainer>
          <Button onClick={createSnippet}>Create snippet</Button>
        </Form>
      </BodyContainer>
    </ModalContainer>
  </Modal>
);
```

So what happens, is actually just nothing. When I try to check what's happing and insert a console.log("check") in the try block I do see it appearing in my console. But no network request or anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a copy of your custom hook in Codepen, removed the useReducer part, used a different HTTP request, and found that I was able to make network calls successfully.

https://codepen.io/goodmorningasif/pen/poyVNMW?editors=0010

Maybe the issue is with your API URL.

Are all these values (specifically `framework`) valid?

```
function createSnippet(e) {
    doFetch(`/snippets/${framework}.json`, {
      description: description,
      category: category,
      title: title,
      snippet: snippet,
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return [mockState, fetchData];
};
```

Should this be `JSON.stringify`? Or does it need conversion? Per [the Axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#example), they're passing in the JS data object as is.

```
const result = await axios[method](url, JSON.parse(data));
```

Also, did you try putting a console log in the catch to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Darn, a console.log() in the catch block did it. I was parsing a json to a json which gave me an error. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You caught it at the same time as I did, but glad I could help a little!